# Elegantly reuse code adding const to a class instantiation

Tags: c++, constants, c-preprocessor

I need to compile the same code with two different libraries. One allows the objects to be const, the other doesn't. The solution that's implemented now looks like this:

```
#ifdef (OLDLIB)
    ClassFoo TheFoo = Bar();
#else
    const ClassFoo TheFoo = Bar();
#endif
```

This is used many times for different classes and impedes readability. I'd like to make the distinction somewhere else.

I guess one could say:

```
#ifdef (OLDLIB)
#define CLASS_FOO ClassFoo
#define CLASS_BAR ClassBar
#else
#define CLASS_FOO const ClassFoo
#define CLASS_BAR const ClassBar
#endif

CLASS_FOO TheFoo = Bar();
CLASS_BAR TheBar = FooBar();
```

But I dislike preprocessor stuff. Is there a nice C++-Way of doing the above? Thanks.

Update 1:
As Peter Wood said, it is possible to just instantiate them non-const. I changed the sentence.

Comment: I wonder what, specifically, about the preprocessor solution you dislike.

Comment: I don't understand. Why can't you pass a non-`const` object to a function expecting `const`?

Comment: @StevenMaitlall Preprocessor solutions make me nervous because I have seen bad things happen where they were used. I only use them if there is no better way and there usually are better ways. Google for what Stroustrup or Stutter have to say about preprocessor stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're stuck with the preprocessor to accomplish your goal.

However, I'd probably write it like this:

```
#ifdef OLDLIB
#  define LIB_CONST
#else
#  define LIB_CONST const

LIB_CONST ClassFoo TheFoo(Bar());
```

Either way is not super elegant but doing it this way at least means that you're only tweaking an object attribute via the preprocessor rather than the whole object declaration.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) to select between two types based on a compile-time variable:

```
#ifdef OLDLIB
constexpr bool OLD = true;
#else
constexpr bool OLD = false;
#endif

std::conditional<OLD, ClassFoo, const ClassFoo>::type theFoo;
                 ~~~  ~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                        true        false
```

*<sup>Since C++11</sup>*

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution seems to be to just use non-const objects and let the compiler automatically add const where the new interface expects it.

Alternately could you use a typedef inside the proprocessor block?

```
#ifdef (OLDLIB)
    typedef ClassFoo InstantiableFoo;
#else
    typedef const ClassFoo InstantiableFoo;
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can typedef

```
// oldlib.h
typedef ClassFoo Foo;
typedef ClassBar Bar;

// newlib.h
typedef const ClassFoo Foo;
typedef const ClassBar Bar;


// the library's user
#include "oldlib.h"       // or include "which_lib.h" that includes
                          // one of oldlib.h newlib.h
#include "your_library_that_uses_the_typedefs.h"

Foo TheFoo = Bar();
Bar TheBar = FooBar();
```

You can parametrize your library's classes and global functions

```
// library.h
template <class Foo>
class SomeClass { }

template <class Foo>
Foo makeFoo() { }

// library_user.cpp

#include "library.h"
SomeClass<const ClassFoo> sc;
sc.method();
const ClassFoo f = makeFoo();
```

You can even hide the type Foo inside of the external libraries

```
// external_library.h
class ExternalLibrary {
     typedef const Foo foo_type;
};

ExternalLibrary::foo_type& foo_identity(const ExternalLibrary::foo_type &v) { return v; }

// your_library.h

ExternalLibrary::foo_type makeFoo() { }

foo_identity(f1);
```